# Lambda Expression usage

Tags: java, lambda

```
        List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(10, -5, 3, 7, 20, -30, -1);
        final int bound = 10;
```

How can i do these steps(square and sum) by Lambda Expresion?

Comment: HI, pls read guide line and tutorail for what to need.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Print with forEach:

```
integers.stream()
            .filter(value -> value <= bound && value >= -bound)
            .forEach(value -> System.out.print(value +" "));
```

Sum:

```
int sum = integers.stream()
            .filter(value -> value <= bound && value >= -bound)
            .mapToInt(value -> value*value)
            .sum();
```

Comment: what if i wanted to keep it in for loop, then mapInt doesnt work

Comment: make it return a list, see the answer of @WJS, it will work

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It takes the elements and streams them, applies your filter and then maps each element to its square.  The boxed operation maps to an `Integer` so it can be collected to the list.

```
List<Integer> squares = IntStream.of(10, -5, 3, 7, 20, -30, -1)
        .filter(value -> value <= bound && value >= -bound)
        .map(a -> a * a)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(squares);
```

Prints

```
[100, 25, 9, 49, 1]
```

You could also have broken it up into parts.

Establish the stream

```
IntStream integers = IntStream.of(10, -5, 3, 7, 20, -30, -1);
```

Now apply it.

```
List<Integer> squares = integers.filter(value -> value <= bound && value >= -bound)
        .map(a -> a * a)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(squares);
```

To get their sum, just do this.

```
int sum = integers.filter(value -> value <= bound && value >= -bound)
        .map(a -> a * a)
        .sum();

System.out.println(sum);
```

Prints

```
184
```